# Can we access MS Graph API's, using same credentials as the paid version of Office365?

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

We have paid version of Office365, so can we able to access MS Graph API's, using same credentials or do we need a seperate account?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can access MS Graph using the same credentials you're using to access Office 365. Have a look at this page that will help you get started on the platform of your choice: http://dev.office.com/getting-started/office365apis.